# How to make multiple HTTP requests in the scope of same session?

Tags: scala, http, session, playframework-2.4

I am setting out to build an instagram bot with Scala/Playframework. I would like to be able to login, like, comment, follow, etc... This means multiple requests through the same session.

So far, I was able to use https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS and was able to login, but the thing is that when I try to run subsequent requests (to like for example), I get rejected, I suppose that WS doesn't keep track of the `csrftoken` returned by instagram.

Is there a clean way or library to keep track of such information for subsequent requests?